# Converting an array formula from MS Excel to Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, excel, google-sheets

I am at my tethers end on a question and was hoping someone on here could point out the simple mistake I am making.
I have a formula that I am using in an excel spreadsheet that works fine but when I import into Google Sheets it ceases to work.

The formula that works in excel is

```
{=INDEX('2009-2010'!D2:D20,MIN(IF(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET('2009-2010'!D2,ROW('2009-2010'!D2:D20)-ROW('2009-2010'!D2),0)),ROW('2009-2010'!D2:D20)-ROW('2009-2010'!D2)+1)))}
```

and the way I try and use it in sheets is

```
=ArrayFormula(INDEX('2009-2010'!D2:D20,MIN(IF(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET('2009-2010'!D2,ROW('2009-2010'!D2:D20)-ROW('2009-2010'!D2),0)),ROW('2009-2010'!D2:D20)-ROW('2009-2010'!D2)+1))))
```

But instead of doing what it is meant to (which is displaying the top visible cell on column 'D' of another worksheet called '2009-2010') it just inserts the whole column.
I have tried a couple work arounds but I am in over my head - **any assistance would be fantastic!**

Somewhat surprisingly I have not been able to find anything(anywhere) about someone trying to do the same function on Google Sheets...?!

Answer (score 0):

This is an oldie, but if someone is still interested one could use this formula instead, in both Excel and Spreadsheet:

```
=INDEX('2009-2010'!D2:D20,MIN(IF('2009-2010'!D2:D20>0,ROW('2009-2010'!D2:D20)-ROW('2009-2010'!D2)+1)))
```

- The `IF('2009-2010'!D2:D20>0` part can also be changed to `<>""` if the values are texts.

The problem is Spreadsheet doesn't treat all array formula scenarios the same way Excel does. For example Excel calculates the `CountA` for each item and returns an array of 0 and 1, and Spreadsheet counts the whole array and returns one count result.

This formula is also more efficient by avoiding the `OFFSET` volatile function.